# Php5 - There is a way to configure different * .ini files for each VirtualHosts?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, ini

I have a doubt about Apache 2.4.7 and Php5, there is a way to configure different * .ini files for each VirtualHosts?

Example, if I have a VH working on **80 port** with the rules of the *global php.ini (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)*, another in **8080 port** that has access to the **exec()** function and another in **9090** with access to **pcntl_fork()** function, that I want is only **9090 can access to pcntl_fork()** but 80 and 8080 not, same for **8080, this VH only can access to exec()** but 80 and 9090 not.

I have been tried with *PHPIniDir*, but when apache loads a * .ini file, the three VH's **(80,8080 and 9090)** can use all functions **exec and pcntl_fork()**,

I tried to use the tags *[PATH=/var/www/vhost_8080]* and *[HOST=localhost:8080]* in the global php.ini to load each function, but phpinfo() does not recognize them , also use the Fcgi module (*FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "/var/www/vhost_8080"*) in VH config setting the path where the ini file is.

Summarized what I want to achieve is restrict the php functions for each virtualhost for security reasons. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Ps. Sorry for the bad english